# How do the cellular capabilities differ between the different iPhone 6s/6s Plus models?

Tags: iphone, cellular-carriers, lte

## Info

Apple lists the LTE band support of its iPhone models on this page: [iPhone LTE Support](http://www.apple.com/iphone/LTE/). It lists more information about the iPhone 6s models on this page, specifically in the Cellular and Wireless section: [iPhone 6s - Tech Specs](http://www.apple.com/iphone-6s/specs/)

Here is a comparison of the iPhone 6s/6s Plus models' cellular specs as of the time of writing this question, noting certification differences in the four major US carriers:

### A1633/34 (Certified US support: AT&T)

- LTE (Bands 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 12, 13, 17, 18, 19, 20, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30)
- TD-LTE (Bands 38, 39, 40, 41)
- TD-SCDMA 1900 (F), 2000 (A)
- CDMA EV-DO Rev. A (800, 1700/2100, 1900, 2100 MHz)
- UMTS/HSPA+/DC-HSDPA (850, 900, 1700/2100, 1900, 2100 MHz)
- GSM/EDGE (850, 900, 1800, 1900 MHz)

### A1687/88 (Certified US support: Sprint, T-Mobile, Verizon)

- LTE (Bands 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 12, 13, 17, 18, 19, 20, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29)
- TD-LTE (Bands 38, 39, 40, 41)
- TD-SCDMA 1900 (F), 2000 (A)
- CDMA EV-DO Rev. A (800, 1700/2100, 1900, 2100 MHz)
- UMTS/HSPA+/DC-HSDPA (850, 900, 1700/2100, 1900, 2100 MHz)
- GSM/EDGE (850, 900, 1800, 1900 MHz)

---

## Question

It appears that the only difference between the two model pairs is the absence of support for LTE band 30 in the A1687/88 models. Am I missing something? Why wouldn't they just make one model pair for US customers (A1633/34)?

Comment: I just spoke (on the phone) to a "technical engineer" at Apple who told me that the difference between models is indeed **only** support for LTE band 30.